# HLS video player in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add basic Hls video player to my PHP script, so that when I run this PHP script it should play in Hls player instead of just generating the URL.

This is my script which works fine:

```pho
<?php

$channel_meta = JsonfromURI("https://catalogapi/TV");
$stream_url = $channel_meta->stream_url_hls;
$tok_json = JsonfromURI("https://TOKENS/live.php");
$video_token = $tok_json->video_token;
$m3u8 = $stream_url.$video_token;
echo $m3u8;

function JsonfromURI($url) {
   $resp = file_get_contents($url);
   return json_decode($resp);
};
?>
```

Comment: You are generating the video URL - now you need to tell the browser to display the video. So you need to use some HTML/JS/CSS on the page. This depends on which tool will you use for that - follow their documentation. For example https://flowplayer.com/developers/plugins/hls

Comment: Based on your needs and the video format, HTML5 does have video capabilities

Comment: oh thanks, i will try Anatolii

Comment: cleptus- i can't use html5, better js i think

Comment: i unable to do so, can anyone help me out with the code.